# Generate Individual serial number for a specific pattern in android

Tags: android

I need to get a new serial in my android app. I need a serial number with a specific pattern every time when a user click a button.
The serial number pattern is:

**[date]_1 ... ... ... [date]_n**

for example, today is 21-09-2021. so first serial number for today will be **210921_1**, the next one for today will be **210921_2**. And for tomorrow the first serial number will be **220921_1**, the next one will be **220921_2**. Like this it will continue.
How can I do it?
please forgive if I make any mistake.

Comment: first part is Simply a date format i.e ddmmyy . Whats n here ? Whatever n is you can append it to formatted date .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step with solving a problem such as this is to break it down into the separate logic elements.

1. Extract Date Today.
2. Check 'number' of previous dates stored.
3. Convert data to DDMMYY format.
4. Append _
5. Append 'number' + 1
6. Increment 'number' counter.

Those are the steps. You therefore need a variable to start with that will contain the current value of the number of serials stored that day, this will start at 0.

Next you now need to understand how to get the 'date' and how to format it. Look at the APIs for [Calendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar) and [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat).

That's about it.

I could post code but, there's a lot of examples for those and, really, with that logic, you should now be able to do this yourself.

Good luck!